# function with if statements that executes code based on clicked elements id

Tags: jquery, html

have a paragraph with a few span tag that have id on them. on my js i have a listener for each one of the tags and a function that is call on all click events. I want to use an if statement to filter an action bases on the id of the tag that was click but i cant seen to get it right.

```
ive tried if($("#id")){do something}
      if(this$("#id")){do something}
```

but i haven't figure out how to narrow it down to the specific tag. it will call the function on click so the listener is right i think. my issues is getting the function to pic what was clicked and react to it.

```
<p id="jobs" >
            <span id="1">Roofing</span><br>
            <span id="2">Siding</span><br>
            <span id="3">Gutters</span><br>

</p>
```

here is the js code

```
$("#1").click(displaySelectedService); 
$("#2").click(displaySelectedService);
$("#3").click(displaySelectedService);

function displaySelectedService(){
    if($("#1")){
       console.log('cliked one');
    }else if($("#2")) {
   console.log("it was not one it was two");
}else {console.log("it was 3");}
```

i want to run code based on the span id that was click. Please explain pros an cons of your answer i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, except you shouldn't be trying to do additional JQuery dom lookups in the click function.  Your problem is that you didn't know that [an additional event parameter can be passed to the callback](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler).  With this event object you can then work with the target of the event (the clicked div) and access it's id.  I've only alerted  it for now but you could do anything you'd like.

```js
$(".clickable").click(myFunction);

function myFunction(theEvent) {
  alert(theEvent.target.id);
}
```

```css
#root {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#one {
  width: 22px;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 450px;
  height: 66px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.clickable:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div id="one" class="clickable">
  
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="clickable">
  
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="clickable">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When using IDs, it's strongly recommended to have them be unique. Here you have two named `"one"`. It is assumed that IDs are unique, and this will break, jsut for an example, the `document.getElementById` function.

Comment: Whoops I already know about unique IDs I was just doing some copy and paste, my bad.  Left unedited so your comment still stands, but it's not that important in the grand scheme of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a unique class to each of the options rather than add click events to each element by their `id`. In the demo below I have added the class `.service` to each of the options. You can then use the jquery selector, using this class, to apply the click event to every instance in one go. This reduces the number of lines of code, and means you can add more services without having to add more event listeners manually.

```
$(".service").click( function() {
  // do something
}
```

The demo then gets the unique `id` of the element clicked, so that you can check it in your `if / else if` statements and perform a different activity depending on which has been clicked. This way you still have the functionality you were originally looking for.

Let me know if you needed something else.

```js
// Add click event to all elements with the class
$(".service").click(function() {

  // Get the id of the clicked element
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  
  // Print to console, just to prove we can tell the difference between the elements
  console.log("Clicked #" + id);

  // Check id against the various options to change outcome
  if (id == 1) {

    // Your 'Roofing' code here
    console.log("Roofing selected");

  } else if (id == 2) {

    // Your 'Siding' code here
    console.log("Siding selected");

  } else {

    // Your 'Gutters' code here
    console.log("Gutters selected");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="1" class="service">Roofing</p>
<p id="2" class="service">Siding</p>
<p id="3" class="service">Gutters</p>
```